# changing the date formatin linux bash

Tags: linux, bash, csv, sed

Regarding an earlier answer, I need to change the date format from yyyy-mm-dd to yyyy/mm/dd.

I was given this answer:

```
sed -i 's@,\(....\)-\(..\)-\(..\) @,\1/\2/\3 @' /home/Documents/blah.csv
```

this works perfectly, for only one instance per line. However one line can have many of these dates, how do I change the sed command so it does it for every instance detected (not just the first).

Example document:

```
2012-09-09,123143,2012-09-09,12837,2012-09-07,2131,2012-08-06,1237
#and many more lines like that.
```

after running the sed command, I get this:

```
2012-09-09,123143,2012/09/09,12837,2012-09-07,2131,2012-08-06,1237
```

It only works on the second date instance, How do i make it work for all of them?

Comment: Maybe it's possible to just replace `-` by `/`. That would go with `tr -- - /`

Comment: You can append the letter `g` as a modifier to the sed command to have it look *g*lobally in each line. However, make sure that all matches remain correct. Example: `sed -i 's@match@replacement@g' document`

Comment: Yes.. the g works.. but it always skips the first one.. so basically im getting this now:

2012-09-09,123143,2012/09/09,12837,2012/09/07,2131,2012/08/06,1237

Comment: It works, I missed he extra commas in there.. basically it has to be this 
sed -i 's@\(....\)-\(..\)-\(..\) @\1/\2/\3 @g' /home/Documents/blah.csv

Answer (score 2):

Use the `g` flag, to make substitutions for every match in a line, not just the first. Also, the first date isn't matched because it isn't preceded by a comma.

```
sed -i 's@\(....\)-\(..\)-\(..\)@\1/\2/\3/@g' /home/Documents/blah.csv
```

This fixes a few issues:

1. Don't bother matching the commas; the 4-2-2 nature of the data should be sufficient, and the first field is not matched because it isn't preceded by a comma.
2. Add the `g` flag following the terminating `@` to replace all matches, not just the first.
3. Added a forgotten `/` between the year (`\1`) and the month (`\2`).